# New Domain wont load on internal network

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory

I just created a website domain ***newventure.com*** it's pointed to our server in the DMZ 192.168.110.3 network

Our internal ActiveDirectory network running ***company.com*** as our AD domain and website domain. Right now I have an "A" record for WWW in our local DNS that points to the internal address of our webserver (ip 10.0.0.5).

How can I get www.newventure.com added to our network dns and point it to our DMZ network?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 options:

1. Create an internal DNS zone - newventure.com and add appropriate records to it. However, you would need to managed both external and internal zones to have them in sync.
2. Create an internal DNS zone - www.newventure.com and create a blank A record.